# Possible to create widgets dynamically?

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic, android-widget

For each Contact, I want to create three checkboxes and a TextView inside an Activity. Is this possible? If so, how? Another stackoverflow answers says No, it's not possible, but I find that hard to believe...

Comment: post the link to the post that says it can't be done.

Comment: Any Android book that introduces widgets will introduce both XML- and Java-driven creation of them.

Comment: OK here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787092/dynamically-creating-widgets-on-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it wouldn't be possible. Since it's "for each contact" I'd imagine you'd want a `Cursor` from the `ContactsContract` content provider. As such, you will also likely want a `ListView` if your goal is to display a list of contacts. Given you have a cursor that has the information for your contact, you'd then utilize a `CursorAdapter` of some kind to map those contacts in the cursor into `ListView` items. Then you'd design your `ListView` item layouts with 3 `CheckBox` widgets and a `TextView` and populate them appropriately. Doesn't seem impossible.

Comment: I can create the set of checkboxes I need along with the TextView that holds the Contact name. However, I have not been able to get an OnClick() event to fire for the individual rows. SO, I'm thinking I will need to dynamically create widets as I loop through Contacts - adding three checkboxes and a TextView for each row in the result set/Contacts Content Provider. I can then query the checkboxes when clicked to see which Contact it is affiliated with, and save accordingly to my SQLite DB. I will assign the Contact's ID or so to the checkbox's Tag property (or whatever it's called in Android).