# How to add Widgets on Button click?

Tags: java, android

I have android app, in this app i have widgets functionality in this app , my point is that how can i be able if some one want to add widgets to desktop in mobile

Comment: What is your question exactly ? you want to add more than one widget or what ? as for users to show widget they just  need to grab it after long press the app widget will shown with other widgets

Comment: dear its so bad for negative vote , if you dont understand then negative vote ?

Comment: i want to add widgets to screen with button click ?

Comment: I do not gave you a negative vote !

Comment: I still do not understand you why you need a button when it's already exist ?

Comment: If you do not create it from the beginning and want to add it at run time like on  button click I think it is not possible check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787092/dynamically-creating-widgets-on-android

Comment: if some one want to add widgets to its mobile screen then he will go to widgets and will drag it to screen i want to add this process with button click ? under stand

Comment: user can add widgets to its home screen from wedgets by select and drag to home sccreen i want this process through button click

Comment: check the answer here it opens widget picker https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100926/how-to-add-a-widget-to-the-android-home-screen-from-my-app  to select it and add it it's up for the user but for doing whole these Programmatically I really don't  know if it possible.

Comment: Thanks so much @Radwa